# Not able to show first controller iOS Swift

Tags: ios

Below is my code, I am unable to load first view controller through this suggest me without using navigation controller embedded.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    let firstViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController")
    self.window?.rootViewController = firstViewController
    return true
}
```

Comment: Is your firstViewController in storyboard?

Comment: Is it's identifier name "LoginViewController"?

Comment: yes, giving this error

Comment: Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?

Comment: What is your storyboard's name you are using. Can you attach an image for me to see. :)

Comment: Have a look at my answer, you can achieve this easily in storyboad with one click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) make sure you are filling in the correct name for your storyboard.
2) check the identifier name for your view controller.

then,

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as UIViewController

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Comment: Great!! Please accept this answer if it works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to do it via code? As your view controller is in storyboard you can just click on the view controller and tick the box to make it the initial view controller, which achieves the same thing as your code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
```

change here your storyboard name.

Answer (score 0):

if you use storyboard, you gotta set the initial view controller in storyboard, "self.window?.rootViewController " won't work
[image]